# Return a list, which contains a pair of elements, but only if the respective elements' sums are odd

Tags: haskell, recursion, modulo

> Implement the `oddPairs :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [(Int, Int)]` function that returns a list of pairs, but only if the parameters' lists' respective elements' sums are odd.
>
> For example:
>
> `oddPairs [1,2,3] [2,2,2] == [(1,2),(3,2)]`
>
> `oddPairs [1,3,5] [2,4,6] == zip [1,3,5] [2,4,6]`
>
> `oddPairs [1,2,3] [1,2,3] == []`

So far, I've tried

```
oddPairs (x:xs) (y:ys) | (x+y) `mod` 2 == 0 = []
                       | (x+y) `mod` 2 /= 0 = [(x, y)] ++ oddPairs (xs) (ys)
```

And on the first example, it returns only `[(1,2)]`, on the second, it returns the correct values but with a `Non-exhaustive patterns` error.

Comment: By the way, the Prelude includes `even :: Integral a => a -> Bool`, implemented using `mod` and `(==)` as you've done here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case the two items are even, you should not just return an empty list, but continue the recursion until at least one of the lists is exhausted, so:

```
oddPairs :: Integral a => [a] -> [a] -> [(a, a)]
oddPairs [] _ = []
oddPairs _ [] = []
oddPairs (x:xs) (y:ys)
    -- keep searching for new items ↓
    | (x+y) `mod` 2 == 0 = oddPairs xs ys
    | otherwise = (x, y) : oddPairs xs ys
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to look at the problem is that you want **only** the **pairs** that have an odd sum. This is a slight difference in emphasis that might lead to the following.

Use the `zip` function to combine each list into **pairs**. Then use `filter` to find the ones with odd sum.

```
oddPairs :: Integral a => [a] -> [a] -> [(a, a)]
oddPairs f s = filter oddPair (zip f s)
    where oddPair (l, r) = not $ even (l + r)
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite straightforwardly with a list comprehension:

```
oddPairs :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [(Int, Int)]
oddPairs ms ns = [(m, n) | (m, n) <- zip ms ns, odd (m + n)]
```

Indeed:

```
> oddPairs [1, 2, 3] [2, 2, 2] == [(1, 2),(3, 2)]
True
> oddPairs [1, 3, 5] [2, 4, 6] == zip [1, 3, 5] [2, 4, 6]
True
> oddPairs [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3] == []
True
```